# How to prevent WP_Query function from returning all posts when empty?

Tags: php, wp-query, functions

For example:

```
function getBlogFeedPosts($settings, $featuredPosts, $exclude_array, $numPosts, $offset)
{
$mbaQueryArgs = [
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'   => $numPosts,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'offset'           => $offset,
    'posts_per_page'   => $numPosts,
    'exclude'          => $exclude_array,
];

if (!empty($settings->blogs)) {
    $mbaQueryArgs['meta_query'] = [
        [
            'key'     => 'feed_id',
            'value'   => $settings->blogs,
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ],
    ];
}

$query = new WP_Query($mbaQueryArgs);

return $query;
}
```

and

```
function getRegCatPosts($settings, $featuredPosts, $exclude_array, 
$numPosts, $offset)
{

$mbaQueryArgs = [
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'   => $numPosts,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'offset'           => $offset,
    'posts_per_page'   => $numPosts,
    'exclude'          => $exclude_array,
];

if (!empty($settings->categories) || !empty($settings->regions)) {

    $mbaQueryArgs['tax_query'] = ['relation' => 'OR'];

    if (!empty($settings->regions)) {
        array_push($mbaQueryArgs['tax_query'], [
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $settings->regions,
        ]);
    }

    if (!empty($settings->categories)) {
        array_push($mbaQueryArgs['tax_query'], [
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $settings->categories,
        ]);
    }
}

$query = new WP_Query($mbaQueryArgs);

return $query;
}
```

I'm calling them like this to be merged later on like so:

```
$queryBlogFeeds  = getBlogFeedPosts($settings, $featuredPosts, $exclude_array, -1, 0);
$queryRegCat     = getRegCatPosts($settings, $featuredPosts, $exclude_array, -1, 0);
$blogFeedPosts   = $queryBlogFeeds->posts;
$regCatPosts     = $queryRegCat->posts;

// Get the IDs from each query
$feedsPosts = wp_list_pluck($blogFeedPosts, 'ID');
$taxonomiesPosts = wp_list_pluck($regCatPosts, 'ID');

//Merge the results and filter out duplicate posts
$postIds = array_merge($feedsPosts, $taxonomiesPosts);
```

the queries are given post ids from user selection on front-end. the problem is that if a user doesn't make a selection that passes data to a query function, that function returns all posts. I understand that parameter '-1' on the functions is to return all posts, but that what I need in this case. I think the issue might be how i'm storing the functions in $queryRegCat and $regCatPosts, but I'm not having any luck here trying to modify that piece or find any solutions  here that fix what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If a user doesn’t select anything, what do you want returned?  Nothing or 5 most recent, something like that.

Comment: I actually don't want anything returned from an unused query. For instance, if $regCatPosts isn't used, and I var_dump it, I get every post on the site, which is then merged into $postIDs. I don't want that in this case, and want it to return nothing.

Comment: Would it make sense then to not run the query at all if `$featuredPosts` or `$excluded_array` are empty?  You could then wrap the entire query in a conditional check and only execute if the two arrays that add specificity are actually present?  So `if( !empty( $featuredPosts ) ) { //run query }`.